# get() and post() methods in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

At the moment, I'm taking the web development course with Node.js.

The question is: I have a simple HTML form where a user can enter the first and the last name. The route for this operation is `/name`.
I have a handler for GET requests where the first and the last names are passed in the URL parameters. Also, I have a handler for POST requests where I can fetch the full name from the request body.

Here is my *index.html* file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title>Hello HTML</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, HTML.</h1>
        <p>Do not use until Challenge #12</p>
     <form action="/name" method="post">
      <label>First Name :</label>
      <input type="text" name="first" value="John"><br>
      <label>Last Name :</label>
      <input type="text" name="last" value="Doe"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
    </body>

</html>
```

Full *myApp.js* file:

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// app.get("/", function(req, res) {
//   res.send('Hello Express');
// });

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.method + " " + req.path + " - " + req.ip);
  next();
});

app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get('/:word/echo', (req, res) => {
  res.json({echo: req.params.word});
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.html");
});

app.get('/now', (req, res, next) => {
  req.time = new Date().toString();
  next();
}, (req, res) => {
  res.json({time: req.time});
});

app.get('/json', (req, res) => {
  if (process.env.MESSAGE_STYLE === "uppercase") {
    res.json({"message": "HELLO JSON"});
  } else {
    res.json({"message": "Hello json"});
  }
});

app.route('/name')
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.json({name: req.query.first + " " + req.query.last});
  })
  .post((req, res) => {
    let string = req.body.first + " " + req.body.last;
    res.json({name: string});
  });
```

When I submit form data, I'm receiving this JSON response:
**{name: "undefined undefined"}**

But all the test are passed.
Nonetheless, why the app behaves this way?

Comment: That should throw an error because `req.body` is `undefined`

Comment: Can you show me the URL after you submitted the form?

Comment: Read [the documentation for body parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser). `require`ing it is not enough, you have to actually do something with it.

Comment: Also note that you don't need to explicitly load body-parser, since it is a dependency of express itself (see also [the documentation for req.body](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body)).

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Comment: You need this before your route handler `app.use(express.urlencoded())`.  That will tell express to read and parse the body of the request and put the results into `req.body`.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks. I've updated my question - now, there is my full .js file. I had something like you wrote. Check it out in my code, please.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for the answers! I'll check all the links you provided. What about the .html file - I didn't write it on my own - it was pre-written before. I'm taking the course on freeCodeCamp.

Comment: Re edit: If I add the missing call to `listen`, I can't reproduce the problem. The JSON has `John Doe` in it with no mention of `undefined`.

Comment: Strangely. Okay, maybe it's a bug of the Replit online IDE (but I don't know why), since I use it to run tests on freeCodeCamp. (I write the solution for the task in the Replit, and pass a link to my solution to freeCodeCamp page)

Comment: @Quentin thank you for your time, I really appreciate it. I'll read the documentation.

Comment: FYI, you can remove both `let bodyParser = require('body-parser');` and  `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));` and use just `app.use(express.urlencodeded(){extended: false})` as body-parser is already built into express.  No need to separately load the bodyParser module.

Comment: If you are still having a problem, then add `console.log(req.body)` in your target route handler and see if it has anything in it and, if so, what the property names are.